# How can i randomize the objects that work as particles when moving from a Force?

Tags: particles

I made a particle force in the middle of a sphere so the elements moves from the center, but its weird because the elements move around but without rotating, as you can see thay are like lines, is there any form to avoid this? Because they look like bricks or something but not actual particles/random things.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try adding some more random movement (e.g. a turbulence force field and/or some brownian motion). Aside from that It'd be helpful if we could have a closer look at your setup.. ;)

Comment: Allright i uploaded a photo

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to make the particles rotate randomly?

Comment: What force field you used ? I can't see it on your screenshot. Please add more (text) details about your setup and what you want to achieve...